# iOS Parse.com Facebook Login - valid email address error

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform, authentication

Using the sample code, I continually get a nil user and an error in the block for the login:

2015-11-09 17:39:16.017[90448:3746935] [Error]: You must use a valid email address. (Code: 142, Version: 1.9.1)
Printing description of error:
Error Domain=Parse Code=142 "You must use a valid email address." UserInfo=0x7fb403c39f20 {code=142, temporary=0, error=You must use a valid email address., NSLocalizedDescription=You must use a valid email address.}

Here's the code:

```
FBSDKAccessToken *accessToken = [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken];
if (accessToken)
{
    [PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithAccessToken:accessToken block:^(PFUser * _Nullable user, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (!user) {
            NSLog(@"Facebook login cancelled.");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"User now has publish permissions!");
            [self loadFBAccountInfo];
        }
    }];
 }
 else
 {
    [PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions:@[ @"email", @"public_profile" ] block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) { // , @"publish_actions"
        if (!user) {
            NSLog(@"Facebook login cancelled.");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"User now has publish permissions!");
            [self loadFBAccountInfo];
        }
    }];
 }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you get an error when logging in without an access token? with an access token? Have you enabled fb login on your Parse Application Settings?

Comment: Sorry, the error was in the cloud code which required an email address - when a user is first created via the Facebook route, it doesn't have an email address...

Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function(request, response) {
   var email = request.object.get('email');
 
   if (!email) {
      response.error('You must use a valid email address.');
   } else {
      response.success();
   }
});

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the error was in the cloud code which required an email address - when a user is first created via the Facebook route, it doesn't have an email address...

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function(request, response) {
   var email = request.object.get('email');

   if (!email) {
      response.error('You must use a valid email address.');
   } else {
      response.success();
   }
});
```